# Resizing an image in matlab without introducing interpolated values

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a categorical image and I need to make it smaller. But, by default, when I use imresize in matlab, the output is not categorical either (it will be continuous). However, there are some methods like Otsu to convert it to categorical image, but I do not want to use those methods.

Is there any method in matlab by which I will be able to resize a categorical image to another categorical image without using any other operation on the resized image?

Comment: do you mean a binary image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use nearest neighbor interpolation, it should only use values that were in the image before, i.e., no weighted averages.

As from [the docs](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/imresize.html), to achieve this, you should add `'nearest'` to the function call to specify the *nearest neighbor* interpolation method. Default is bicubic interpolation.

Comment: 'nearest' is enough accurate for re-sizing?

Comment: @Sam Whether it is accurate _enough_ or not depends on your requirements. You haven't been very clear about this. The usual approach is to just try it and see if it turns out to be effective. Another partially related note: If you want to resize the image by factors of 2, also have a look at http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/impyramid.html