# Resizing an image in matlab preserving the original values

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a gray-scale image which represents a probability distribution. That is, its values sum to one. I wish to downscale the image, without changing the original probability values.

I tried to apply imresize using nearest neighbor interpolation (see code below) as suggested in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022994/resizing-an-image-in-matlab-without-introducing-interpolated-values), but the values change. Actually, they zero out. Is there another way to achieve that?

```
> unique(prob_map)   % a grey-scale image representing a pdf
ans =
     0
0.4231
0.5769
> sum(ans)
1
> I = imresize(prob_map, [192,256], 'nearest');
> unique(I)
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is throwing away a subset of your pixels. You are basically subsampling your image. You just happened to be unlucky and throw out all non-zero ones.

The right approach would be to bin groups of pixels together, adding their values. You cannot do this with resampling or interpolation.

One simple approach would be to add up N consecutive rows, then add up N consecutive columns:

```
A; % your input
B = reshape(A,N,size(A,1)/N,[]);
B = squeeze(sum(B,1))';
B = reshape(B,N,size(B,1)/N,[]);
B = squeeze(sum(B,1))';
```

What this does is not preserve individual values, but preserve the sum of probabilities:

```
sum(A(:)) == sum(B(:))
```

This is most likely what you are after.

Note that this does require that the sizes of A divide evenly by N. You can pad your input with zeros to make it so:

```
A = padarray(A, ceil(size(A)/N)*N-size(A), 0, 'post');
```

Comment: By the way, I somehow assumed you were using MATLAB. I guess 'imresize' did that to me. If so, you might want to add the MATLAB tag to your question.